# Setting map extent using offset in ArcGIS API for JavaScript v3.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents

I am trying to set map extent using an offset because there is a panel floating over the left side of the map and sometimes, when I zoom to a feature extent, the feature is partly hidden behind it.

I would like the extent to be **always displayed and CENTERED in the map section that is not hidden by the panel**

For instance the normal behavior is like below, but some of the feature is hidden behind the panel:

[image]

I would like to find a way to center the feature in the map section that is not hidden by the panel like the red rectangle below:

[image]

This is what I tried so far without success:

```
function zoomToExtent(extent) {
  var hiddenMapPartTopLeft = map.toMap(new ScreenPoint(0, 0)),
      hiddenMapPartBottomRight = map.toMap(new ScreenPoint(panel.position.left + panel.position.width, map.container.offsetHeight));

  var dx = new Extent({
    xmin: hiddenMapPartTopLeft.x,
    ymin: hiddenMapPartBottomRight.y,
    xmax: hiddenMapPartBottomRight.x,
    ymax: hiddenMapPartTopLeft.y,
    spatialReference: map.spatialReference
  }).getWidth();

  extent = extent.offset(dx, 0);
  map.setExtent(extent);
}
```

The map zoom way too far to the right.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Confirming: this is the 4.x API?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentionned its 3.x

Comment: Are the units of the map and panel the same?

Comment: The map units are in meters but the panel is in pixel

Comment: If you are using Web AppBuilder (I believe it is Launcpad theme). One of a workaround could be to hide/minimize the 'LayerList' widget(floating panel), when you zoom to a feature extent.
If possible you can switch to 'Tab' theme - which has a separate tab for rendering the widgets without floating on map area.

Comment: You mentioned that when you run your code, "The map zoom way too far to the right.", can you share a screenshot of that result?

Comment: @whyzar I dont have a screenshot, but I can say that the map is moving very far from the feature that it was not visible in the screen. Anyway just offsetting the feature extent is not enough because it does not solve the problem of the zoom level if the feature does not fit completely inside the map part

Comment: @BelowtheRadar is this something you are looking for? https://targetingtools.ciat.cgiar.org/app/ The panels appear when you click on the dock buttons at the bottom left side of the app.

Comment: @wondim no, not really. I dont want to change the panels, I want to offset/expand the extent of a feature when I zoom on it in order to make it centered in the right part of the map (red rectangle)

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I have made some fixes to your code and it works on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Here is the correct code.

```
function zoomToExtent(extent) {
  var hiddenMapPartTopLeft = map.toMap(new ScreenPoint(0, 0)),
      hiddenMapPartBottomRight = map.toMap(new ScreenPoint(panel.position.width, map.container.offsetHeight)); // Removed panel.postion.left

  var dx = new Extent({
    xmin: hiddenMapPartTopLeft.x,
    ymin: hiddenMapPartBottomRight.y,
    xmax: hiddenMapPartBottomRight.x,
    ymax: hiddenMapPartTopLeft.y,
    spatialReference: map.spatialReference
  }).getWidth();

  extent = extent.offset(-dx, 0); //shift to right with -dx and to left with +dx
  map.setExtent(extent);
}
```

Also see [the jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/andex/hm14bxnk/1/). The shift the map after searching a location, click on `My custom search box:` and anywhere on jsfiddle window.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be different - not to set the extent - just recenter the map after zooming to the desired geometry.

I've created a little [codePen](https://codepen.io/nettaben/pen/eYmVOdN)  based on the geolocate example, which creates a point and zoom to it, it also zooms in the start on Eiffel tower

I've changed the example so there will be side and bottom divs, as in your map.

After the geolocation and zooming:
- Create new definitions for 'centered' map width and height
- Center the map to the new position - all based on screen points - since the map is already focused on the desired geometry - we just need to move the map center according to the side and bottom divs.

Note: since the polygon can be hidden by the panels - I've added a setZoom to current zoom level minus 3 (can be 1 as well I guess).
GL!

EDIT: In order to activate the example - click on the locate button  OR wait 2 seconds..
EDIT2: Basically I created a function that recenters the map when needed - like your `zoomToExtent`. It recenters the map according to the x,y of the current screen. You will also want to change the zoom level, depends on the polygon

```
function centerMap(zoom) {

  // Get dimensions of side div
  var sideDiv = document.getElementById('sideDiv');      
  var centerdMapWidth = map.width - sideDiv.getBoundingClientRect().right;
  // Create centered screen X
  var centeredMapX = centerdMapWidth/2;

  // Get dimensions of bottom div
  var bottomDiv = document.getElementById('bottomDiv');         
  var centerdMapHeight = bottomDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  // Create centered screen Y
  var centeredMapY = map.height - centerdMapHeight/2;

  // Create new center point
  var scrPoint = new ScreenPoint(centeredMapX, centeredMapY);         
  // Create the center point in map units
  var centeredMapPoint = screenUtils.toMapPoint(map.extent, map.width, map.height, scrPoint);
  //Zoom out (to polygons...)
  map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 3)
  // Move to the new center
  // Added a timeout to see the difference between the points
    map.centerAt(centeredMapPoint);
    document.getElementById('sideDiv').innerHTML = "New center: " + centeredMapPoint.x + "<br>" +  centeredMapPoint.y;

}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you, but I am looking for a one shot function. Also, your codePen is not working.

Comment: It took me some time to re organize my answer. I hope it can help you.